# Binary search not returning the position

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, search, binary-search

this code is used to create an array filled with 10 random integers. It sorts the array and then inputs the array into a binary search function. I do not get the position of where my search key is positioned.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>


int binary_search(int array[], int search, int strt, int ending)
{
   int middle;

   middle = (strt + ending)/2;//splitting the array in half to compare the search key

   if (search > array[middle]){binary_search(array, search, middle + 1, ending);}
   else if(search == array[middle])
    {
     printf("Your search key is indicated in %d position the array Ferrari\n", middle + 1);
     return middle;
    }
   else{binary_search(array, search, strt, middle -1);}


 return -1;
}


int main()
{
  srand(time(NULL));//random number seed generator
  int Ferrari[10];
  int size = 10;
  int selection;
  int temporary = 0;//I'm using this variable to store 
                    //the value returned from linear_search()
  int start = 0;
  int end;
  int i;

  //this is to generate a random number between 0 and 101   
  for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {Ferrari[i] = rand() % 100 + 1;}

   //printing the initial array     
   printf("\nThe array Ferrari consists of -> ");

   for(int i=0; i<10; i++){printf("%d, ", Ferrari[i]);}


//--------------------------SORTING--------------------------------------------
 for(int f = 0; f < (size - 1); f++)
{
    for(int kk = 0; kk < (size - 1 - f); kk++)
      {
        if(Ferrari[kk] > Ferrari[kk +1])
          {
            int Te_mP;
            Te_mP = Ferrari[kk + 1];
            Ferrari[kk+1] = Ferrari[kk];
            Ferrari[kk] = Te_mP;
           }
      }
  }

  //----------------------------------------------------------------------------

   //printing the array after it has been sorted    
   printf("\n");
   printf("\nThe sorted array Ferrari consists of -> ");

   for(int i=0; i<10; i++){printf("%d, ", Ferrari[i]);}

    start = 0;
    end = i -1;

  //this will be used to implement the searching algorithm  
   printf("\n\n");
   printf("Please enter a number to test if it is included in the array or not\n");     

   scanf("%d", &selection);


   temporary = binary_search(Ferrari, selection, start, end);


 return 0;
 }
```

I keep getting the answer that the search key is positioned in ``0 of array Ferrari. How do I resolve this?

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong over here. Much appreciated.

Comment: "How do I resolve this?" The usual way is to do debugging to find the problem. Run the program in a debugger, step through the code and examine what it does to help you find out where it starts going wrong.

Comment: What is the input you gave ? What is the output you get ? What is the output you expected instead ?

Comment: As @kaylum says, you need to debug this, but a debugger (tool) is not the only option.  Scatter enough `printf`s around your code to allow you to follow its progress, then compare each step to what you'd expect.  You'll be sure to find the bug this way.  For example, here: `if(Ferrari[kk] > Ferrari[kk +1]){` print out `kk` and the values of `Ferrari[kk]` and `Ferrari[kk+1]`.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker input to the function would be my search key and the sorted array. say the array had a 44 in the 3rd position of the array and my search key was 44. I should get an output saying that my search key is positioned in 3

Comment: You are missing `return` before each recursive call of `binary_search`.

Comment: @FAFSHOCK : I understand that, but you should include that in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is occurring because you are using uninitialised variable `i` here:

```
end = i -1;
```

Note that the scope of variable `i` declared in loop *init clause* is different from the scope of variable `i` declared in function block.

```
for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
    ^^^^^^^
   // The scope of i declared in loop init clause is limited to the loop.
```

To fix the problem, you can use the `i` declared at function block scope as the loop variable, like this

```
for(i=0; i<10; i++){
```

Now, after the loop finishes, the variable `i` will hold its last value until it's value explicitly modify. But using `i` to identify the size of array down the code may cause **several problems** as it is not tightly coupled with the size of array and `i` may be get modified by other part of code. So, it is not the right idea to use `i` to identify the size of array.

Since, you are having a variable `size` which hold the size of array `Ferrari`, you can do:

```
end = size - 1;
```

No need to have another variable to keep the track of *size* of array. The problem with this is that you have to keep updating the `size` whenever you change the array size. An alternative of this would be to use a macro to define the array size.

The most appropriate way to set the `end` of array would be:

```
end = (sizeof(Ferrari) / sizeof(Ferrari[0])) - 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at this line

```
end = i - 1;
```

Where is i initialized? 
In your loop you have

```
for(int i=0........
```

Note by giving `int i=0` it means you are creating a new variable *i* within the `for` block. So this doesn't alter your original *i* variable declared at the top. Try using `end = size - 1` or it's a best practice to define a constant for this purpose.

```
#define ARR_SIZE 10
```

in loop

```
for(i=0; i<ARR_SIZE;i++)
```

Then initialize `end = ARR_SIZE -1;`

And one more thing in your `binary_search` function is that you don't handle the case when the key is not present in the array.
Something like

```
if(end==start && array[end] != search)
    return -1;
```

This checks when the search space has only one element and that is not your search element, it means it doesn't exist so we return -1. 
Hope this helps